# terminating the input at '=' character

Tags: c++

i want to terminate the input at '=' character for example that i have given the input 2 +3=
as soon as i give the '=' character it should process the input and display the output.
Any help.. Spaces can also be included in the input. (it should not take any input after '=' character) the pl is c++ or c

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post some code. also, C and C++ are two almost completely different languages.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious approach would be something like `std::getline(intput, your_string, '=');`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the scanf function as a starting point.

Comment: scanf is evil.  The recommendation by experts is to read the data into a string then use sscanf (that is the string version).  For C++, I suggest std::getline and std::string.

Comment: Yes, though I thought scanf would the simplest place for him to start.